# Understanding async await in python socket io / aiohttp server

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, socket.io, python-asyncio

I am trying to setup an socket.io server using [python-socketio](http://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).
Here is a minimal working example:

```
import asyncio
from aiohttp import web
import socketio
import random

sio = socketio.AsyncServer(async_mode='aiohttp')
app = web.Application()
sio.attach(app)

@sio.on('connect')
def connect(sid, environ):
    print("connected: ", sid)

@sio.on('sendText')
async def message(sid, data):
    print("message ", data)
    # await asyncio.sleep(1 * random.random())
    # print('waited', data)

@sio.on('disconnect')
def disconnect(sid):
    print('disconnect ', sid)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    web.run_app(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

This runs fine, and I can execute (here in node.js) for instance

```
const io = require('socket.io-client');
const socket = io('ws://localhost:8080');
socket.emit('sendText', 'hey 1')
socket.emit('sendText', 'hey 2')
socket.emit('sendText', 'hey 3')
```

If I run the server and run the node script above I get server-side

> connected:  c1e687f0e2724b339fcdbefdb5aaa8f8
>
> message  hey 1
>
> message  hey 2
>
> message  hey 3

However, if I uncomment the lines with await sleep in the code, I only receive the first message:

> connected:  816fb6700f5143f7875b20a252c65f33
>
> message  hey 1
>
> waited hey 1

I don't understand why the next messages are not appearing.
Can only one instance of `async def message` run at the same time? Or why?

I am sure that I am not understanding something very fundamental about how this works. I would be very grateful if someone could point out what I am not understanding.

Comment: When you run the sleep, it stops for that amount of time and therefore any messages being received will not be processed correctly.

Comment: It isn't just that call to the coroutine that sleeps?

Comment: The await will stop the executing thread and wait for that function to finish running, and therefore won't process anything else until that has finished waiting

Comment: @Jaxi: there are no threads. `await` will tell the event loop that other coroutines can execute, but it usually *will return* to the coroutine once the `asyncio.sleep()` time has passed.

Comment: @Jaxi: `asyncio.sleep()` does **not block execution**, it is specifically designed to just put a coroutine on the inactive queue until the time has passed. You seem to be confusing this with `time.sleep()`.

Comment: You are creating fractional seconds by using `random.random()`. It depends on the event loop if such small numbers are even supported. Could you try with `asyncio.sleep(1)` and see if that makes a difference? I'll try to run this locally too, what OS are you using?

Comment: @Jaxi: in other words, I don't think you understand how Python coroutines, asyncio and `asyncio.sleep()` actually work.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Thank you! I just tried with `await asyncio.sleep(2 + 5 * random.random())` instead. Still the same behaviour. I'm on Windows, but doesn't seem to work on linux either.

Comment: I can't actually reproduce this, not on OS X. Can you try again with *whole numbers*, so perhaps use `random.randint()` or `random.randrange()`, or just *hardcode* an integer number?

Comment: It fails with hardcoded numbers as well. Also just tried the code on ubuntu as well -- fails there as well. This is stranger than I thought it would be.

Comment: @MartijnPieters which versions are you using? I'm on `aiohttp==2.3.7` and `python-socketio==1.8.4`.

Comment: @Julius: Bingo. My `aiohttp` is fairly old, `aiohttp==1.0.2`; our `python-socketio` versions matched. But when I upgraded `aiohttp` to version 2.3.7 I see the same problem.

Comment: @Julius: and 2.2.5 doesn't exhibit this behaviour, but 2.3.0 *does*. We are on to something here.

Comment: AH! Great to know. Thank you so much for helping out!

Comment: @Julius: I'm not that familiar with aiohttp and python-socketio to go debug this further, but you may have grounds for a bug report (start with python-socketio), there may be an incompatibility between projects here. You have a simple enough case to reproduce.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'm the author of the python-socketio package. There are two problems here, I think. I can answer your question:

> Can only one instance of async def message run at the same time? Or why?

My Socket.IO server serializes the events that are received from a given client. So for example, if client A sends an event that runs for one minute, any additional events sent by A during that minute will be queued, waiting for the first event to complete first. If client B sends an event during that minute, it will be handled immediately. The reason why events from a client are artificially serialized is to prevent race conditions or other side effects from occurring as a result of two or more handlers for the same client running in parallel. This serialization of events can be turned off, with the `async_handlers` option:

```
sio = socketio.AsyncServer(async_mode='aiohttp', async_handlers=True)
```

Using aiohttp 2.3.7 and `async_handlers=True` your three events are received at more or less the same time, and then all handlers wait in parallel during their sleep periods.

Unfortunately this does not explain the 2nd and 3rd events never reaching the server. I have verified that these events are properly queued and executed in sequence with aiohttp 2.2.5, but this breaks with 2.3.0 all the way to 2.3.7. My current theory is that a change that was introduced in 2.3.0 is causing these messages that arrive while the task is sleeping to get dropped, but haven't found why that happens yet.

Comment: Fantastic! `async_handlers=True` was exactly what I needed, and it now all works with aiohttp 2.2.5. Thanks for a great library. I hope you manage to figure out the >2.3.0 issues.